# R Shiny Manipulating Datatable

Tags: r, shiny

I want to first upload a CSV file, then manipulate how my datatable is presented based on what is chosen in the sidepanel. This is a sample of my CSV data:

[Students Data Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvUFu.png)

How this works is I'll first choose my Department: if I'm the Principal, the whole datatable is printed. If I'm the Teacher, I can only see SubmissionDate, StudentID, and Class. If I'm the Student, I can only see SubmissionDate, StudentID, and Student.

Furthermore, I intend to filter by SubmissionDate. Whoever I am, if I choose a range of dates, only those rows within the date range will be presented. For example if I'm A03 Sam, if I didn't choose a date range I will see 2 rows. If I chose a date range for a single year, I will see 1 row only.

My problems are:
1. My datatable apparently cannot run. Is it because of using fread? I get this error: "Warning: Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext: Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)"

2. How do I filter my datatable from multiple inputs?

This is my R Shiny code:

```html
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Students"), 
  sidebarLayout( 
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file1", 
                "Choose CSV File", 
                multiple=TRUE, 
                accept=c( "text/csv", "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain", ".csv")), 
      checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),
      radioButtons("disp", "Display", choices=c(Head="head" , All="all" ), selected="head"), 
      
      tags$hr(), 
      radioButtons("dept", 
                   "Department", 
                   choices=c(Principal="Principal" , Teacher="Teacher" , Student="Student"
      dateRangeInput("dates", "Date Range"), 
      textInput("studentid",
                "StudentID", 
                value="Enter StudentID:" )
) ), 
                         
  mainPanel(tableOutput("contents") ) ) )
  
library(shiny) 
library(data.table) 
server <- function(input,output) { 
  data <- fread(input$file1$datapath, 
                header=input$header, 
                sep=",", 
                quote='"') 
  
  output$contents <- renderDataTable( 
  if(input$disp=="head" ){return(data))} 
  else {return(data)}
  ) 
} 
  
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Hi Please refer this [How To Ask Good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) , Good question asked get up voted easily, voted question get more attraction to get good answer.

Comment: Hi lai, it would probably be best if you split this question up into minimum reproducible examples for each of the issues you are having. The error you are reporting now is not related to `fread`, but to the lack of a `reactive` on your server side. The `reactive` context lets you compute new values based on changing `input$variables` - then you use those new values in `render` operations. Your `input$disp` is not inside a `reactive({ })` block giving your current error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to properly set all the `reactive` components.

Moreover, if you want the data to be properly filtered, you need to manipulate it in `server`.

Below is a working script based on your example:

```
library(shiny) 
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Students"), 
  sidebarLayout( 
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file1", 
                "Choose CSV File", 
                multiple=TRUE, 
                accept=c( "text/csv", "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain", ".csv")), 
      checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),
      radioButtons("disp", "Display", choices=c(Head="head" , All="all" ), selected="head"), 

      tags$hr(), 
      radioButtons("dept", 
                   "Department", 
                   choices=c(Principal="Principal" , Teacher="Teacher" , Student= "Student")),
      dateRangeInput("dates", "Date Range"), 
      textInput("studentid", "StudentID", value="Enter StudentID:" )
    ),
    mainPanel(DT::dataTableOutput("contents"))
  )
)


server <- function(input,output) { 

  file <- reactive({

    if (input$header) {

      return(fread(input$file1$datapath, 
                   header= TRUE, 
                   sep=",", 
                   quote='"'))

    } else {

      return(fread(input$file1$datapath, 
                   header= FALSE, 
                   sep=",", 
                   quote='"'))
    }

  })

  file_head <- reactive({

    if(input$disp == "head") {

      return(head(file()))

    } else { return(file()) }

  })

  data_filtered <- reactive({

    if (input$dept == "Teacher") {

      return(file_head() %>% mutate_at(.vars = 1, funs(as.Date(strptime(., format = "%Y%m%d")))) %>%
        select_at(.vars = c(1:2, 4)) %>%
        filter_at(.vars = 1, any_vars(. >= input$dates[1] & . <= input$dates[2])))

    }

    else if (input$dept == "Student") {

      return(file_head() %>% mutate_at(.vars = 1, funs(as.Date(strptime(., format = "%Y%m%d")))) %>%
        select_at(.vars = c(1:3)) %>%
        filter_at(.vars = 1, any_vars(. >= input$dates[1] & . <= input$dates[2])))

    }

    else { 

      return(file_head() %>% mutate_at(.vars = 1, funs(as.Date(strptime(., format = "%Y%m%d")))) %>%
        filter_at(.vars = 1, any_vars(. >= input$dates[1] & . <= input$dates[2])))

    }

  })


  output$contents <- DT::renderDataTable({

    if (is.null(input$file1)) {

      return(NULL) } else { return(data_filtered() ) }

  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I've seen you also want to have a text input for `Student ID`.

As you haven't specified anything with regards to this, I haven't included it as filter (you can always filter the DT itself with `Search`), but the examples above should get you started should you want to proceed in that direction.